# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: sensors

Tags: qt

I am trying to build the INscore software. Running `make` in the build directory (as the installation instructions suggest) leaves me with the following error:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: sensors

Any one has an idea how to solve this? In the file library.pro the is a line which adds sensors to QT:

`QT += quick qml quickwidgets sensors`

Comment: How have you installed Qt?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have BunsenLabs (Debian), i haven't installed qt, it was preinstalled

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/a/577334